# Mysql query IF statement not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please help me with this query:

```
SELECT
    w.aboutme,
    w.user_id,
    IF ( (SELECT db2.user_relation.id FROM db2.user_relation
          WHERE w.user_id = db2.user_relation.user_id AND
          db2.user_relation.clients_id = 1), "true", "false") as selected,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name SEPARATOR ", ") FROM services
     WHERE w.user_id = w.user_id) as services
FROM websites w, db2.user_relation
```

Everything works fine if db2.user_relation has some records but if it's empty the query returns 0 results, even though there are 4 records in the websites table.

And everything works if I take the IF statement out. So it appears my IF statement needs some tweaking.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should remove `db2.user_relation` from your `FROM` clause:

`FROM websites w`

You do not use any columns from it, and if no rows exist, no rows are returned by your query.

Comment: Thanks, geez so easy

Answer (score 0):

Your query is much better written in the form of `JOIN` that using correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT  w.aboutme, 
        w.user_id,
        CASE WHEN u.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS Selected
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name SEPARATOR ', ') as services
FROM    websites w
        LEFT JOIN db2.user_relation u
            ON  w.user_id = u.user_id 
                AND u.clients_id = 1
        LEFT JOIN services s
            ON w.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP   BY  w.aboutme, 
            w.user_id
```

In your original query, the reason why you are getting empty rows when `db2.user_relation` has no row is because you are performing cartesian join (CROSS JOIN) between the two tables, so if one of the tables is empty then obviously the final result is also empty.

`FROM websites w, db2.user_relation` is the same as `FROM websites w CROSS JOIN db2.user_relation`